# "Kapo" de Brokolo?

Tags: single-word-requests

Mi serĉas la vorton por la "tuta aĵo" de brokolo. Ne ero de brokolo, sed aro de brokolo.

En la angla: head of broccoli

En la franca: tête de brocoli

En Esperanto: kapo de brokolo? brokolokapo? brokolaro? brokograpolo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi konas du similajn vortojn: *kapeto* kaj *butono*. Kaj ekzistas kun alia signifo *burĝono*. Kapeto de ajlo, de brokolo = eta parto de la tuto, kvazaŭ arbeto.

Do *kapo* laŭ mi estas en ordo.

---

***Petitaj fontoj:***

Mia respondo baziĝas precipe sur mia Esperanta partnereco; kiel pri tiu *kapeto de ajlo*. Serĉo en Reta-Vortaro:

> [ReVo]
> Supra ekstremo de stara objekto; antaŭa ekstremo de kuŝa objekto: kapo de pinglo

**kapo de arbo**
23. H. C. Andersen, trad. L. L. Zamenhof: Fabeloj, vol. 4, Lasta sonĝo de maljuna kverko

Ia (elstara? voluma?) *ekstremaĵo* do.

**florbutono**
BOT Flor**kapeto**, burĝono de floro; butono1.d: ruĝeta florbutono, entenanta ebriigan aromon [13].

Comment: Cxu vi povus iom pli klarigi vian respondon? Cxu vi havas fontojn kun difinoj de tiuj vortoj kiujn vi mencias?

Comment: @AntoniaMontaro mi provis.

Answer (score 0):

Mi kredas, ke la partoj de brokolo estas [infloresko](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infloresko) kaj [tigo](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tigo).